# Waiting for WPF window in non-WPF project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, forms

Why is it that if I call a WPF form from another project type (e.g. a console application or XNA game), the main application doesn't wait for the form to close before ending (and subsequently closing the form)?

I know with a dialog box I can make the main class wait for a reponse, how can I make it do that with my form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open the window in modal mode using the [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) method - the ShowDialog method only returns after the window was closed. Otherwise you can either wait until the [Closed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closed.aspx) event is fired or wait until [Application.Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows.aspx) collection is empty (meaning the application has no WPF windows left).

For more information about window closing in WPF, refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.close.aspx).